# External URL linking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I have the following code:

```
<script>
        var fileContent;
        $.ajax({
            url : "text.txt",
            dataType: "text",
        ...
```

It loads the text from a .txt file in order to obtain the data. If the text.txt is on the same path as the html code, it loads the data. However, if I type for example (placing the file in a different folder):

```
url: "../../../files/text.txt"
```

It does not allow me to obtain the file. Any ideas of how to do it or how to implement it without changing the code in a significant way? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a directory structure?

Comment: Yes. You can see it in the next image. http://imgur.com/js575UU . The html code is located on app/views/Application/index.html, and the txt file is located in simulationsData/Experiment-XX/text.txt", starting from the image attached.

Comment: You have the URL wrong then. You don't mention `simulationsData` anywhere in `"../../../files/text.txt"`

Comment: Also - showing a single level of your directory tree isn't very helpful, nor is expressing it in the form of a link to a picture on a third party website.

Comment: Directory structure would be useful here as Daan says, You can also try to add leading backslash to start from root location. Double check if "files" directory exist and You havent make mistake in amount of parent folders  - "../"

Comment: I believe Your url should be something like this : `../../../simulationsData/Experiment-XX/text.txt `

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't post the whole content. I've posted the directory using imgur as here I can't post an image. The whole directory can be seen here http://imgur.com/HB3sUhI . And the ../../files directory was just an example, actually I wrote: url : "../../../simulationsData/Experiment-XX/text.txt". Huge thanks!

Comment: I've added an error alert and it tells me the following: "error
 NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied" How can I solve it?

Comment: @jquery_stack — See my answer. In particular the second section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three possible causes of this:

**You are using HTTP**

You are using HTTP and the path you are trying to access is not exposed by your web server. (You cannot access files above the directory root by default).

You need to give the file a URL on your web server and request that URL.

**You are using local files**

Different browsers have different security restrictions for Ajax on local files.

You can get this problem if the file is in a directory above the HTML document (some browsers only allow you to access files in the same or a lower directory).

You can resolve this by using HTTP. Ajax in general works very poorly without HTTP.

**You simply have the URL wrong**

Correct the URL.

Comment: What is the best option if I don't want to change drastically my code, just change the browser (which one allows it?) or use http(how would the code change?)? Thanks!

Comment: Use HTTP. The code wouldn't change. You'd just install a webserver and go to `http://something/` instead of `file://something`.

Comment: I'll try to find information on how to implement it and see if it is simple. Thanks!

Comment: I've downloaded Apache and whenever I type http://localhost/text.txt I see the data on the web browser. Then I just change to

url: "http://localhost/text.txt"

but the document does not load the file properly :/. Any idea?

Comment: Load the HTML document over HTTP too.

Comment: If I have unserstood you well, what I've done is put the html file in the same folder as the txt in the htdocs folder, but then when I try to load it, Firebug reports that $ is not defined and it doesn't load :/

Comment: You have to load jQuery before you can use it.

Comment: You shouldn't get that unless you are hosting the website on a different server to the text file. Make sure you have `http://localhost/something` in the address bar of your browser.

Comment: HUGE THANKS! I was loading the text file well but the html file, even though it was in the htdocs folder, was charged in the browser indicating the path and not using the localhost. You've made my day!